# How to storage data in server memory in Nextjs 13 app directory

Tags: server-side-rendering, next.js13

I have a basic form in Nextjs with some validations and when I click on the submit button I handle the event and I create a JSON with the retrieved data.

Right now I'm doing a console.log of the JSON and everything goes pretty well.

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {

      if (formIsValid) {

         const trabajadores = [];
         additionalWorkers.forEach((element, index) => {
            trabajadores.push({
               nombre: element.name,
               dni: element.dni,
            });
         });

         const jsonToSend = {
            nombre: nombreComunidadRef.current.value,
            direccion: {
               direccion: direccionComunidadRef.current.value,
               codigo_postal: direccionComunidadCPRef.current.value,
               municipio: direccionComunidadMunRef.current.value,
               provincia: direccionComunidadProvRef.current.value,
            },
            representante_legal: {
               nombre: nombreRepresentanteRef.current.value,
               dni: dniRepresentanteRef.current.value,
            },
            nif: cifComunidadRef.current.value,
            email: correoElectronicoRef.current.value,
            videovigilancia: {
               numero_camaras: numCamarasRef.current
                  ? numCamarasRef.current.value || 0
                  : 0,
               funcionamiento: checkedFuncionamientoInputs,
            },
            datos_trabajadores: {
               trabajadores: trabajadores,
               registro_jornada: checkedRegistroJornadaInputs,
            },
         };

         console.log(jsonToSend);

         /* TODO - Storage 'jsonToSend' in server memory to display it later */

      }
}
```

What I need to do now is storage that JSON in the server memory, not in localStorage or sessionStorage (since this is client side), I want to save it just like in nodejs.

I know that it won't persist but I don't care, is just for a demo and learning purposes.

I created this API Route: `/app/api/addComunidad/route.js`

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function GET(res) {

    /* TODO - 

        1. Get the JSON

        2. Storage it in the server

        3. Return OK response

    */
    
    const data = await res.json()
    return NextResponse.json({ data })
}
```

I can't find any information on the Internet and ChatGPT and other AI only gives you legacy code that doesn't work in the Nextjs13 with the new app directory features